# Using Mutter as pure WM

Tags: gnome, window-manager, openbox, mutter

I am making an Archlinux USB stick. I usually use GNOME as my DE, but it is too much heavy for a 16GB USB Stick. The last time I build an USB stick I used openbox, and I liked it, but I was wondering if it's possible to use Mutter instead of openbox as a pure WM.

I've never sawn anyone using Mutter purely, like we do with openbox. Is it possible? If yes, is this also viable?